# Can a global ref object be saved when using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

The situation is as follows: The dio used by the network request has a custom interceptor. The interceptor's onResponse method judges that if the server returns code == 404, it will trigger the user's logout operation, and some data will be cleared with the logout operation. for example：

flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.0-dev.7

RequestInterceptor.dart

```dart
class RequestInterceptor extends InterceptorsWrapper {

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    if (response.data['code'] == 404) {
      // Force users to log out
      // ref.read(userProvider).logout();
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

But how do I get the ref object to get the userProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

Instead, create your RequestInterceptor inside a provider and pass it the "ref" object

```dart
class Example {
  Example(this.ref);
  final Ref ref;
}

final provider = Provider((ref) => Example(ref));
```